# Unable to import view from different app

Tags: django

I'm trying to import a view from one app into another app but it's giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 332, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 397, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 536, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 529, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 673, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/myproject/myproject/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    path('home/',include('wapperapp.urls')),
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 673, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/myproject/wapperapp/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/myproject/wapperapp/views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from myproject.vidbrowser.views import index
ImportError: No module named 'myproject.vidbrowser'
```

I've imports like this in other parts of the project which isn't giving any error but this one does...

I am sure the thing I'm trying to import exists but I can't seem to find out why it's not working.

Does anyone know what the problem is here?

Comment: You should show the layout of your project and the `views.py` that is failing. It's harder to tell what's going on from the traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer `myproject` directory (that contains `manage.py`) is on the Python path. Therefore the import should be:

```
from vidbrowser.views import index
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from appname import views
```

and then

```
views.index
```

or

```
from appname.views import index
```